# Unable to find or create trash directory

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

I just created an ntfs partition for Windows 7 dual booting. I tried deleting a few files from a folder in the windows drive, but I get the error `Unable to find or create trash directory`. I can create files and folders just fine, and I can delete from the command line with `rm`. I just can't delete with my context menu or with the del key. Why isn't is letting me and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/192629

There is no solution as of yet, the work around is to add an entry in `/etc/fstab`

You can do this with `ntfs-config`, a graphical tool, or the command line.

### ntfs-config

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config

gksu ntfs-config
```

You then change the ownership and prmissions of the ntfs partition.

### command line

Edit `/etc/fstab`

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/fstab

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add a line for your ntfs partition. If you use the `permissions` option you can then set permissions on ntfs partitions.

```
/dev/sdxy /media/your_mount_point ntfs-3g user,locale=en_US.utf8,permissions 0 0
```

For additional information on mount options see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Once you have the correct permissions,

```
cd /media/your_mount_point
mkdir .Trash-1000
```

Change ".Trash-1000" you your UID (first user is 1000, use the command `id` to show yours)

```
id
```