# Unable to find or create trash directory on ext4 drive

Tags: nautilus, trash

I have a dual booted laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu on it.  Most of the time when I try to delete a file I get the following warning:

`Unable to find or create trash directory`

See this dialog box:

[image]

I have tried the following answers for xubuntu located at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262817/unable-to-find-or-create-trash-directory)

I have checked and I do own my trash directory

`sudo chown -R $USER ~/.local/share/Trash`

My user ID is `1000` and I have tried:

`$ sudo mkdir -p /.Trash-1000/{expunged,files,info}
$ sudo chown -R $USER /.Trash-1000`

And this has not worked either.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91894/unable-to-find-or-create-trash-directory) seems to be only for NTFS file systems, but I have an ext4 file system.

How can I get a working trash folder?

Comment: did you check that your user id is indeed 1000? If not Trash-1000 is not going to work

Comment: @Rinzwind yes I checked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have two Ubuntu systems installed in different disks of one machine.
I encountered the same problem when deleting files on another disk and I solved it by a method similar to https://askubuntu.com/a/262827/582507

First, confirm that your normal user is ID "1000":

`$ id`

Then go to the mount point i.e. the root directory of the other disk.

```
$ cd /media/username/root_of_the_disk
$ sudo mkdir -p .Trash-1000/{expunged,files,info}
$ sudo chown -R $USER .Trash-1000
```

Done.

Comment: in my case the hard drives are in /mnt/<AN-ID>, in media is empty and didn't work for me apply this  /mnt/<AN-ID>,